# DNS Apache redirect for domain names held elsewhere

Tags: linux, apache, dns, virtualhost

An external company holds the name servers for several domains for a web site which I host.

I host the site and have a vhost setup with the domainName and domainAlias for:

- www.example.com
- admin.example.com

The external domains also need to redirect to the site:

- www.somedomain.com
- www.anotherdomain.com

**What must I add to my vhost container file to redirect all requests for somedomain and anotherdomain to the main www.example.com**

> (I plan to manage the www and non www
>   requests with mod_rewrite.)

Answer (score 1):

The way I did this was to create a new vhost container for all the alias domains and point them to a new directory in my web site.

- www.somedomain.com
- www.anotherdomain.com
- somedomain.com
- anotherdomain.com

In the new directory I added a mod_rewrite script to redirect ALL the requests the main page

- www.example.com

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```